# Fancybox popup prevent when checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

i have a problem with checkbox in image.While clicking on image fancybox opened fine.If i click on checkbox again fancybox opened.It should not be opened when checkbox click.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="picture"> 
<a  href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/313/19831416459_5ddd26103e_m.jpg" class="fancybox popup_fancy"  rel="gallery1" id="fancybox_popup"> 
<img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/313/19831416459_5ddd26103e_m.jpg" alt=""> 
<div class="img-overlay">
<input type="checkbox"  class="img_checkobx" name="imgcheckbox"  onclick="checkBox(this);"/>
 </div></a> </div>
```

**Image will appear like this**

[image]

and **fancybox js** like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });

});
```

prevent fancybox popup when checkbox is click event. Could anyone suggest how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stop the `propagation` of `event` to `siblings` by using `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` on `checkbox click` as below:

```
$('.img_checkobx').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rncpm4eg/)**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with Firefox browser. when i click on Checkbox it again move to the image displaying screen with out popup.Could you help me in Firefox. Chrome working fine

Comment: What version of FF you are using?

Comment: i am using FF version 41.0

Comment: You want that `checkbox` to be inside `img-overlay` div?

Comment: Yes. is not possible with inside `div` ?

Comment: Even am confused.. For me here `checkbox` gets disappeared once clicked... So was thinking how if we keep it outside!!

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent fancybox on click of checkbox

```
$('.img_checkobx').click(function(){
   $.fancybox.cancel();
});
```